How to apply pattern to some specific log?
I have a spring boot application and I would like to use some specific pattern if log class comes from aus.gov.mkt but I didn't find any way about how to do it.
I have read many topics and tried to create a logback-spring.xml and set on app.properties but it applies to entire log.
logback-spring.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "timestamp": "%date{ISO8601}",
                        "myCustomField": "fieldValue",
                        "relative": "#asLong{%relative}",
                        "message": "#tryJson{%message}"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
                <loggerName />
                <logLevel />
                <message />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>

app.properties
logging.pattern.console=LALALA\n

When I was running on WildFly it was possible to log application specifig messages to a log file and wildfly server to another file.
How can I achieve the same using stdout when running spring boot?
Is there anyway to print different log patterns on stdout based on class who is logging? As exampl, if package is aus.gov.mkt I would like to write log only from message (%message)
